# How to define miners ACL on a private chain

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, private-blockchain, mining-pools, solo-mining

is there a way to manage "allowed" miners in ethereum `private chain` ?

the idea is to have some sort of `access control list` of miner addresses which are allowed to seal a block.

in case the above is not possible, maybe there is any way to disable `solo mining` and allow only `pool mining` instead ?

how would one approach such scenario ?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned a private chain on ethereum, [Quorum](https://truffleframework.com/tutorials/building-dapps-for-quorum-private-enterprise-blockchains) from JP Morgan is a go at that. It's a **permissioned**, private fork of ethereum.

Also, there is a little bit of a misunderstanding I feel(maybe on my part), if you are talking about a private chain that you manage.

> You are in-charge and infact, **responsible** for providing your own miners.

The official documentation for Ethereum on setting one up is [Here.](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Private-network)

But I would recommend reading [This](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/08/07/on-public-and-private-blockchains/) if you are unsure of the differences and use cases between private and public blockchains.